# Magento admin redirecting secure URL after disabling secure URL via database

Tags: php, mysql, http, magento, https

I have a **magento** website in production server with secure URL, and its working fine.

After taking the backup and upload it into my testing server, i tried to disable secure url. For disabling secure URL I am followed below steps.

1.In my phpmyadmin--> core_config_data table I have changed `web/secure/use_in_frontend, web/secure/use_in_admindata` is `1 to 0.`

2.changed the URL paths in secure and Unsecure to my testing server path, changed `https` to `Http`.

After deleting **cache folder**, my frontend working fine except wishlist, checkout,etc pages, but if am loading admin URL its redirecting to secure URL and its not working.

Please help me to get out of this problem.

Comment: go to inspect element and change `http` to `https` or vice versa and check whether the wishlist or checkout page working fine or not. if they still not working.. then the problem is not related to your url changes.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried it, but still no luck, its again redirect to https page, and shows the error "Secure Connection Failed"

Comment: Finally I got the solution :-) its about redis session extension, after disabled the module everything working fine

Comment: nice.. what was the issue?